# Ampliación de numero de caracteres en campo "Observaciones" en JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

tengo un campo que se llama Observaciones que tiene un número máximo de 100 caracteres y me gustaría ampliarlo a 4000 caracteres. Estoy utilizando JSP y necesito utilizar un textarea, pero para pasarle el numero máximo hasta 4000 caracteres tengo que hacer una función JavaScript, pero ando muy perdido con JavaScript.
Os adjunto mi código:

```
                    <div class="div_sol">
                        <span>Observaciones:</span><br>
                        <span>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${ accion == 'consulta' }">
                                    <html:text styleClass="input_deshabilitado_sol" style="width:800px" readonly="true" property="observaciones" title="Debe introducir las observaciones" maxlength="100" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <html:text styleClass="input_habilitado_sol" style="width:800px" readonly="false" property="observaciones" title="Debe introducir las observaciones nuevas" maxlength="100" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Me refiero, donde pone maxlength="100" me gustaría ampliarlo a 4000, pero en vez de utilizar un text, necesito utilizar un textarea, y por lo visto para los textareas no puedo utilizar maxlength, tendría que ser con una función JavaScript, ¿como podría ser la función javaScript? y ¿como la llamaria dentro de mi codigo?

Gracias.

---

Me da el siguiente error al ponerle el textarea, por eso decía que no me deja utilizarlo:

GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet pctJspServlet lanzó una excepción
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /tamaño/prueba.jsp (línea: 349, columna: 9) El atributo maxlength no es válido según el TLD especificado

Yo me refiero en la línea a ponerlo así:

`<html:textarea styleClass="input_habilitado_sol" style="width:800px" readonly="false" property="observaciones" title="Debe introducir las observaciones" maxlength="4000" />`

Lo estoy haciendo en un archivo Prueba.jsp, ¿a que puede deberse?

Answer (score 2):

Claro que si puedes usar [maxlength](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)

```html
<textarea maxlength="4000">
texto con 4000
</textarea>
```

También lo puedes hacer por javascript de la siguiente manera:

```js
document.getElementById("textArea").maxLength = 4000;
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```