# Ajustar los textos y mantener el tamaño de la lista desplegable en JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy aplicando en las opciones del selectpicker de BootStrap un substring JSP genérico, para que no me descuadre y se mantenga la lista desplegable a tamaño fijo mientras se realiza la búsqueda en texto. Aquí el código de ejemplo:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-8 selectpicker">                                   
        <label style="display:block;"><s:message code="permissions.item"></s:message></label>
         <div class="form-group col-md-8" style="width:103% !important;">
             <f:select data-live-search="true" path="codItem" id="itemsSelect" name="codItem" class=" chosen-select form-control">
                 <f:option value="-1" label="---"><c:out value=""/></f:option>
                 <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="i">
                     <f:option label="${item.itDenominacion}" value="${item.itCodigoInterno}">${item.itCodigoInterno} - ${item.itDenominacion.substring(0,20)} </f:option>
                 </c:forEach>
             </f:select>
         </div>   
    </div>
```

Añadiendo a esto, el máximo de caracteres a mostrar es de 90. Aún así, si aumento el substring a 35, me desaparece del todo :/

Mi consulta es: ¿existe forma de ajustar los textos y mantener el tamaño de la lista desplegable, estilo que hace Excel?

Otra pregunta parecida que me he encontrado, a modo de orientación: [Ampliación de numero de caracteres en campo "Observaciones" en JSP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235051/ampliaci%C3%B3n-de-numero-de-caracteres-en-campo-observaciones-en-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la clave a mi consulta. Se trata de usar `fn:lenght()`, para que después puedas usar substring con mucha soltura.

Quedaría de esta forma dentro del select:

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(item.itDenominacion) gt 90}">
        <f:option label="${item.itDenominacion}" value="${item.itCodigoInterno}">${item.itCodigoInterno} - ${item.itDenominacion.substring(0,90)} </f:option>
    </c:when>    
    <c:otherwise>
        <f:option label="${item.itDenominacion}" value="${item.itCodigoInterno}">${item.itCodigoInterno} - ${item.itDenominacion} </f:option>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703965/checking-for-string-length-in-expression-language